# Blank email is sent with Send Email connector in Mule 4

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

I am using Send Email connector (SMTP configuration) to send email to gmail. It is observed that sometimes email is sent with blank body. Though in the mule log I am able to see that the email body is constructed correctly just before the Send Email connector, but the email sent is having blank body.

Even though this issue is occurring very rarely but would like to know how we can avoid such situation and is there way to handle this situation? Also, what could cause this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Mule 4 and what version of the connector? Please also share the flow snippet. What are you sending as payload, what is the content type?

Comment: The connector version is 1.2.1 and mule runtime version is 4.3.0. I am sending a JSON payload in the email body and the content type is text/plain. The email is send at global error handler level. As mention this issue occurs very rarely and it can't be replicated.

Comment: Did you try updating to the last version of the connector? https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/connector/connector-email

Answer (score 1):

There could be two (and more) possibilities:

1. Your payload being json is not getting read correctly, try `payload.^raw` when working with email body json. Had to do this when sending a multipart/form-data containing json content for email service
2. Having said this is a rare scenario it could be possible that your error flow is itself throwing an error ( either while building the body / while calling email end-point) which throws off the body and in the 2nd flow error type being changed without a body the email is sent across? Check your flows make sure http calls are surrounded with Untill-successful scope..

With more info, we could dive deep. What do you think ?